# Kafka Streams - Joining Stream record on KTable with multiple fields

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

This is probably a silly question but I wonder if it's possible to join a KStream on two fields with a KTable/GlobalKTable? For example let's say I have this object that's the value of the records in the KStream.

```
{"gameId": 1, "awayTeamId": 1, "homeTeamId": 2}
```

I will have a KTable/Topic that looks like this -

```
{"teamId": 1, "teamName": "Team 1", "teamId": 2, "teamName": "Team 2"}
```

I want to join both the `awayTeamId` and `homeTeamId` with a KTable so that I can enrich the message so that the resulting record will look something like this...

```
{"gameId": 1, "awayTeamId": 1, "awayTeamName": "Team 1", "homeTeamId": 2, "homeTeamName": "Team 2"}
```

I'm guessing you could maybe have a `branch` with one branch handling the `awayTeam` join and another `branch` handling the `homeTeam` join and maybe end up creating an entirely new record with a `map` or `mapValues` call and maybe combining the two separate branches? I'm not sure if this is a viable method or if there are other avenues to pursue.

Comment: What is your KTable key?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax it's just something named "teamId". Ideally both awayTeamId and homeTeamId will map to an entry in the KTable's key. But I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: (1) If you want to do a stream-table join, boths keys (ie, stream/table) need to be the join attributes. (2) Setting a new key in the stream is easy via `selectKey()`. If the table as only of of both join attributes as key, you can also do a `filter()` after the join to check if the second join attributes also satisfy the join condition.